# 2004 Grand Am won't start up despite functioning electricals

Tags: security, no-crank-no-start

My 2004 Pontiac Grand Am's battery is good, lights, radio and everything.

However, when I turn the key on to try and start it, the security light turns off, no sound is made, until I turn the key back to off and put it back into the on state again.

My car is unable to start up. I believe it has something to do with the security light. But I'm not sure. Has anyone faced such a problem as well?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Just because the battery will power lights, radio, etc. does not mean it has the ability to start the car. What happens if you try jump starting? Have you taken the battery to be tested? How old is the battery?

Comment: Its easy to know if its your security causing trouble. Just do this : Insert key and turn ignition to "ON" (do not crank). IF security light is solid or flashing then the immobilizer is active for one or more reasons. If the light comes on and then goes out and stays out then the immobilizer is deactivated and your no crank is being caused from something else. From your description, it honestly just sounds like the battery is bad or there is a bad connection for it.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical problems can be tricky but often they can be solved easily too. The first (easy) thing to do is clean the battery terminals and check your connections. To do this you need the tools to remove the ground terminal first, then the positive, and use a battery terminal cleaner's wire bristles to clean all corrosion off the contacts and terminals. This corrosion is common and can allow enough current to pass for the lights but not the starter. Make sure the battery is fully charged, tested good and the terminals themselves are not broken. Tighten them securely, positive side first. If this doesn't help, then test your starter solenoid and starter. It could also be your neutral safety switch (keeps car from starting in gear). As you see, it gets more tricky from here. Research your problem by using your favorite search engine to find info by entering phrases such as "2004 Grand Am won't start". Try different phrases. That's how I found that your security system disables the fuel system, not electrical system. Good luck

Comment: Its pretty common on GM's the dash goes out for a second when cranking (tho its not common it stays off like OP is experiencing so I assume their having battery/connection issues). Couldn't tell you why they do it but I remember it doing it a lot on Cadi's and Buick's when cranking after programming keys.  Pretty sure happened often across the board for the pk3 and pk3+ systems.